# Will jQuery $.ajax without full url remain https if original page load was https?

Tags: jquery, ajax, https

Will the following jQuery AJAX request use HTTPS if the original web page load was via HTTPS?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) { alert(data); }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a relative URL works relative to the current host, protocol and port.

Comment: that was my recollection, just looking for a quick confirmation, Thanks!